# What is the expected CP after evolving an Eevee with 376 CP?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am playing Pokemon GO and have caught an Eevee with 376 CP. How high will its CP be after evolving?

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult question to answer without knowing how the server generates Pokemon evolutions but I'll try and push you to the answer you need.

Behind your Pokemon you will see a semicircle with a dot on it, this indicated what percentage your Pokemon is to achieving it's maximum cp (This number changes every profile level-up). your Eevee might for example have a max cp of 400 so your percentage would be around 93.75% of your Pokemon's maximum. Now when you evolve a Pokemon what happens is the new Pokemon gets that percentage applied to it (93.75%) but since it will now have a higher maximum cp, for example 1000, It's new cp will be 93.75% of 1000.

Now taking this into account, we don't actually know yet how the Pokemon's max cp scales with accounts, we can only guess, but it will be scaled to your pre-evolution Pokemon

Answer (score 0):

After Evolution you can expect an increase of ~150%`*`. In your case your Eevee (Vaporeon, Jolteon or Flareon) should have around 1000 CP`*`.

`*` *Based on own game experience. (This only applies to Eevee.)*

Comment: 150% of 376 is 564.  Am I missing something that would make it 1000?

Comment: Yes, you missed the original CP. 564 + 376 = 940. It's increased *by* 150%.

Comment: @CarlKevinson If you want to treat it like that, it's ~2.5x the pre-evolved strength, or ~250%, then your maths make sense. I never did like math word problems in high school... They always tricked me.